# GCP get notification when task queue is retrying

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I would like to set up a notification system in Google Cloud Platform for when my task queue retries x number of times. How can this be done?

Comment: You could have your code send you an email.  I think the retry info is available in the headers.